# Display multiple Image on Curl Api on a each account with different a API url

Tags: php, arrays, api, curl, php-curl

I am trying to display the multiple image on each account on a different API URL!
On each account displaying the image like
Bob has 4 images on his account and it will display that all on data!
I can only fetch 1 image on when adding integer!

Example:

```
$image = $data["result"][THIS IS INTEGER]["image"];
$image = $data["result"][THIS IS INTEGER]["image"];
$image = $data["result"][THIS IS INTEGER]["image"];
$image = $data["result"][THIS IS INTEGER]["image"];
```

How can I fetch each images using array on curl

The image below is the result I want

[image: Sample Image]

This is the sample code I made

```
 <?php
 
 $query = 
    "SELECT 
    * 
    FROM 
    user 
    ";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $total=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $id= $row['id'];
    $age = $row['age'];

        //* first API//
        $url = 'https://api.sample/.$id;
        $ch=curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $r=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = json_decode($r, true);
        $email = $data[email];
        
        
        This is the image part
        //* second API //
        $url = 'https://api.second-sample/.$id;
        $ch=curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $r=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = json_decode($r, true);
        $image = $data["result"][ THIS INTEGER ]["image"];
        
        ?>
        
        <?php ECHO the DATA HERE ?>
        
        
        
        <?php } ?>
```

Second API sample DATA result

```
{"total:4","results":
[
"id":"0"{
"id":"32",
"name-of-image":"lovelife",
"image":"http://sample-storage-image.com/image1.png"
}
"id":"1"{
"id":"52",
"name-of-image":"forrest",
"image":"http://sample-storage-image.com/image2.png"
}
"id":"3"{
"id":"2",
"name-of-image":"sand",
"image":"http://sample-storage-image.com/image3.png"
}
"id":"3"{
"id":"5",
"name-of-image":"water",
"image":"http://sample-storage-image.com/image4.png"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you iterate correctly through each Image you are making only one major mistake!

If you save it to $image = ... you overwrite the $image every time you get the next image...

you should:

```
$image[] = $data["result"][ THIS INTEGER ]["image"];
```

or

```
$image[ THIS INTEGER ] = $data["result"][ THIS INTEGER ]["image"];
```

and then display each: for example:

```
print_r($image[0]);
```

or

```
print_r($image[1]);
```

or

```
print_r($image[ THIS INTEGER ]);
```

(I'm assuming that  THIS INTEGER  is unique!)

etc' at each correct line..

It is one user... however there are multiple images - this requires and array....:)

Comment: I will try this! :D

Comment: DOes the first curl and second is no conflict to each other! Or do I need to rename each variable?

Comment: I tried this but not working         foreach ($data as $r)
        {
        echo $r["result"][0]["image"];
        }

Comment: foreach($data["result"] as $r){echo r['image];)

Comment: Also if doing this this way consider also doing $image[$row['name']][] =

Comment: What Can I replace on the integer [0] so it will display all the image?

Comment: Total:4 result: 1 2 3 4, How can I display this 1 2 3 4 images :D

Comment: foreach($data['result'] as $r){$image[] = $r['image'];} - this should create an array from 0 - how many images there are in $image.  so $image[0] will be "http://sample-storage-image.com/image1.png" and $image[1] = "http://sample-storage-image.com/image2.png" etc

Comment: Oh yeah if you are talking about displaying than you need to use a loop again...;)

Comment: Yes! Can you post the code.. Im still confuse :) Its really hard for me because I am a still a student ! 

Becasue when I tried to loop it! It only display 1 name and not displaying the other name!
On bob displayed But the name josh is not display! 
It display the 4 image on bob! But nothing on John!

Comment: Display multiple Image on Curl Api on a each account with different a API url

Comment: I presume we have $image... so we  loop through it on the page :  foreach($image as $img){?>"<img src="<?php echo $img;?>" ><?php} - for example this is how u loop through the $image array and display each image...

Comment: <?php
$query = 
"SELECT * FROM user ";$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);$total=0;while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){$id= $row['id'];$age = $row['age'];?>
<?php echo $fname ;?>
<?php
$url = 'https://api.sample/.$id;
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$r=curl_exec($ch);

Comment: curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($r, true);
$email = $data[email];
  
$url = 'https://api.second-sample/.$id;
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$r=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($r, true);
$count = $data["total"];
for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++)
{
$image[] = $data["result"][ THIS INTEGER ]["image"];?>
<?php echo '<img src="'.$image[$x].'">';?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

Comment: Displaying the data goes outside of our while ofcourse and inside a loop like I wrote a comment ago...

Comment: Yes I already Tried it but it display only 1 account with 4 image on it! And its not displaying the other 1!  In example! It only display BoB with 4 image But john is missing! And display nothing on john!

Comment: img src unknown

Comment: That is what I meant... if you are trying to create data for more than one account you should use inside the foreach($data['results'] as $r){$image[$id][] = $r['image'];} then , when we are displaying we should use either foreach($image as $keyId => $img){foreach($img as $im){?>"<img src="<?php echo $im;?>" ><?php}}  basically we have created a $image[USERID] array - which can hold several images ... so if we know the id we want to display we can only use one loop : foreach($image[$TheId] as $img){?><img src= ....}  if you are displaying them by order of appearance than use the first example..

Comment: What you have answered is looping and duplicating the image

Comment: I got my question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68620621/fetch-each-user-and-each-user-has-multiple-image-on-different-api-and-data-on-di

Comment: Check out my 2nd example and see that I already told you to use a loop within a loop...: foreach($image as $keyId => $img){foreach($img as $im){?>"<img src="<?php echo $im;?>" ><?php} <= this is a 2 loop solution ... where I print the $im only in the 2nd loop.... :)

Comment: Problem is already solved my friend thanks