# Fetch each user and each user has multiple image on different API and data on different API too

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I was trying to fetch the data! With different API! My problem is While fetching the images! It creates duplicate and the image will mulitply!

I want my result to be!

```
Name1 AGE1 image1 image2 image3 image4
Name2 AGE2 image2 image2 image3 image4
Name3 AGE3 image3 image3
Name4 AGE4 image4 image4 image4 image4
```

But the result that show on my code

```
Name1 AGE1 image1 image1 image1 image1
Name2 AGE2 image2 image2 image2 image2 image1 image1
Name3 AGE3 image3 image3 image2 image2 image1 image1 image2 image2 image1 image1
Name4 AGE4 image4 image4 image4 image4 image2 image2 image1 image1 image2 image2 image1 image1
```

Here is the code I used

```
  <?php
    $query = 
    "SELECT 
    * 
    FROM 
    user 
    ";
    $rows =array();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $rows[] = $row;
    }
    
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $url = 'https://api.user.com/'.$id;
        $ch=curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $r=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = json_decode($r, true);
        $stats =$data[status];
?>
        <tr><td>
<?php 
        $urlserver = 'https://api.images.com'.$id;
        $initiate=curl_init($urlserver);
        curl_setopt($initiate, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result=curl_exec($initiate);
        curl_close($initiate);
        $code = json_decode($result, true);
        foreach($code["results"] as $result)
        {
            $images[] = $result['image'];
        }
            foreach ($images as $img)
        {
        
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $img;?>" ></td>
<?php } ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $stats;?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Data Results

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pls share what holds image array or pls be more specific about input

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the data result! I already Updated !

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved

by using loop inside the loop

```
foreach() {
//#value
}
//value{
for i value here
{
the other loop
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my problem

```
foreach() {
//#value
}
//value{
for i value here
{
the other loop
}
}
```